# How do I make the cell Range work in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I have a problem with the autofill function. I want to use the macro to fill in the date until there is nothing left in B. The problem is that there are some gaps there. Can I change the code so that it fills up to the last line in B. I tried it with the code below. However, it does not work.

[image]

```
Sub fill()
    Sheets("Table1").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""",R[-1]C,RC[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Dim last As Long
    Range("C2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & last)
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Y**ou do not need such a lengthy process. You can do it in just couple of lines. For example

```
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
```

Here is an example. Assuming that your range is from `C2` onwards as shown below.

[image]

Try this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Table")
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("C3:C" & lRow)
        
        Dim visibleCells As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set visibleCells = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not visibleCells Is Nothing Then
            visibleCells.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

**Worth a Mention**

1. Also avoid using `Select/Selection/Activecell` etc. You may want to read up on [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
2. You do not need VBA to achieve what you want. You can achieve the same using few clicks.

**NON VBA Method**

1. Select your range. In this case `C3:C13`
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the **Go To** dialog box
3. Click **Special** button
4. Select the **Blanks radio button** and click **OK**.
5. In the Formula bar type `=C2` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key and you are done

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: I was about to describe your Non VBA method: I learnt it about 20 years ago during a course and since then, I've never stopped being surprised about the power of MS-Excel :-)

Comment: Yup Excel still surprises me :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! Works perfectly, thanks for the one with how to avoid selection as well :)